# Xamarin send IR signal (Android)

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have used Arduino to detect some signals of TV remote. I want to send that signal through android IR blaster to control TV on button click using Xamarin. I searched it for whole day and couldn't find anything. Please give me some suggestion.

Comment: I've never tried this, but the code sample here appears to be relevant: https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/ApiDemo/Hardware/ConsumerIr.cs

Comment: what specifically is "android IR blaster"?  Does it come with documentation?  Is there an API?